# bootstrap5 nav-link not color blue and not hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css

i added bootstrap5 CDN link to study bootstrap nav , but when i added nav-link to my link tag  , its has the right styles except that the blue colour is absent and its not hovering. but same code works well in W3schools and codeply.com.
pls i need a hand here

this is my work

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
 


`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>`
<body>
    `<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg>
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>`

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this: you are missing class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" of the end "

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
 


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>`

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```